# Enviar CSV a una API mediante POSTMAN

Tags: php, api, csv, post, symfony3

Estoy usando Symfony 3 para crear una API que recive un fichero CSV y lo va leyendo.
Esta es mi ruta:

```
/**
 * Recive a file
 *
 * @Route("/get/file", name="get-file")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
 public function getFileAction (Request $request) {

    return $this->json(array(
       'status' => 'success',
       'code' => 200,
       'data' => $request,
    ));
 }
```

He creado una Colección en Postman que me llama a esta ruta y devuelve correctametne los datos:
[image: BodyResponse]

He intentado pasar el CSV mediante el siguiente formulario:
[image: formWithCsv]

- Cómo puedo enviar un CSV a una API mediante POSTMAN u otro servicio?
- Cómo podria hacer unas pruebas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta tu petición POST enviando el archivo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]